# How to find the correlation between numeric and non numeric data using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

From a dataset that appears like the below dataset, I want to find the correlation between familiarity level of neural network to being in PhD. So far, I have tried using pearsonr() and .corr() python funtions for finding correlation between numeric data. How should I proceed in the case like the below one where I need correlation between numeric and non-numeric data?

```
 University     Degree Type     Neural Networks familiarity level
 Virginia         PhD                  2
 Bloomington      PhD                  3
 Toronto          PhD                  2
 Waterloo         Ms                   1  
 Germany          Ms                   1
 Nigeria          Ms                   2
```

Comment: Turn your non numeric data into numeric data so that `PhD` becomes `1`, `Ms` becomes 2, etc?

Comment: Correlation is not an appropriate measure to see the relationship between a categorical and numerical variable. You should provide more info on your variables but in general you can run an ANOVA to see the association between categorical and numerical variables. @AriCooper-Davis 's suggestion won't work as you'll assign arbitrary numbers to categories and you'll get a meaningless number in return.